# How to get field in mongoose by using index number?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here are mongoose documents.

```
Foods
{name: 'Beer' }
{name: 'Hamburger' }
{name: 'Potato' }
{name: 'Pizza' }
{name: 'Banana' }
```

How can I pick up specific document, by using index? For example,

```
[0] ---> return name : 'Beer' 
[3] ---> return name : 'Pizza'
```

like this, I think about a way to do it.

```
var arr = [];
foods.find({},function(err, food){
    if (err) return next();

    food.forEach(function(current){
        arr.push(current);
    });
});
```

If with this code, I can get field to using index number, like `arr[0], arr[3],...`. But this have to make another array, I think there is better way to do it, Can you give me a hint... Thanks.

Comment: What order of the documents you are expecting? Inserted order?

Comment: @AnandS Yes, but anything I don't care !

Comment: Then ```find()``` callback will already return you an array of documents right? ```food[0]``` and  ```food[1]``` should work right?

Comment: @AnandS I didn't know that. I'm an idiot! But If I want to use it outside of function, should I save it to another array.? I want to pass it to another function.

Comment: you don't have to save it in an another array. Pass ```food``` as a parameter to that function. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp